# I am making a bot hat gives a role to a user but it get's error that the bot doesn't have permissions

Tags: discord.js

(the code)

```js
const Command = require("../Structures/Command.js");

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "give-role",
    description: "gives you the role",
    permission: "ADMINISTRATOR",
    async run(message, arguments, client) {
        const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (!targetUser) {
            message.reply("Tag the user that you want to give the role to");
            return;
        }

        arguments.shift();

        const roleName = arguments[1];
        const { guild } = message;

        const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => {
            return role.name === roleName;
        });
        if (!role) {
            message.reply(`There is no role called: ${roleName}`);
            return;
        }

        const member = guild.members.cache.get(targetUser.id);
        member.roles.add(role);

        message.reply(`That user now has the role : ${roleName}`);
    }
});
```

(error message)

```
/home/runner/Discord-manager/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350
      throw new DiscordAPIError(data, res.status, request);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/runner/Discord-manager/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/runner/Discord-manager/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async GuildMemberRoleManager.add (/home/runner/Discord-manager/node_modules/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberRoleManager.js:124:7) {
  method: 'put',
  path: '/guilds/911548130917498901/members/854133415364263976/roles/924275494810165259',
  code: 50013,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

The error is DiscordAPIError: 50013, the error is getting because the prompt says the bot do not have permissions but I added administrator but it still says it doesn't have permissions and I do not know why. Please help me (sorry if my english is bad :() )

Comment: have you given the permission in the server(as if was a common user) or in the developer portal?

Comment: Adding `ADMINISTRATOR` permissions isn't always enough when it comes to roles, you need to ensure the bot's highest role is above the role you are attempting to add.

Answer (score 0):

The bot may be trying to give a role higher than the one your bot has. To fix this, drag the bot's highest positioned role over the role you are trying to give.

**Credit:** [Reddit Comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Discord_Bots/comments/7ttd58/get_missing_permissions_when_trying_to_add_a_role/dtf3ouh/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the position of the role before trying to add it to the user, for example:

```js
if (message.guild.me.roles.highest.position <= role.position) {
    message.reply(`${role.name} is higher than or equal to my highest role.`);
    return;
}
```